# Google Cloud Composer: Save on costs

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am trying to figure out how to save on costs via Google Cloud Composer. Is there anyway to spin down the server when none of your dags are running? Then spin it up again when a dag needs to run?

It's costing way too much since I believe even though my dags are not running the server remains up and we're getting charged.

Thanks,

Comment: Unfortunately googles requirement for the use of a db-n1-standard-2 immediately adds $170 USD per month to the cost of an environment.
I can run it locally with SQLite - its untenable to set up multiple environments with this requirement

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For now, there is no possibility to enable/disable a Composer environment. In order to save money on a server that is not in use, there is a need for a feature similar to autoscaling, for which a [request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/117119946) has already been filed.
On [Medium](https://medium.com/condenastengineering/automating-a-cloud-composer-development-environment-590cb0f4d880) site, you can find a lot of useful information, regarding saving costs.

One way to control your costs in Cloud Composer is to use autoscaling. The amount of nodes can be set to autoscale in GKE cluster, follow [this guide](https://medium.com/traveloka-engineering/enabling-autoscaling-in-google-cloud-composer-ac84d3ddd60). Smaller size of Cloud Composer environment and shorter running time would be best practice.

Cloud Composer charges for compute resources allocated to an environment, components continue to run even when none DAGs deployed. There's not much you can reduce/turn off, you may consider another platform services, such as Dataflow, which is serverless.

I hope you find the above pieces of information useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can now take a snapshot from GUI or [v1beta API](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.locations.environments/saveSnapshot) then delete the environment. When you want to work on it, simply create a new environment and load the snapshot from GCS via GUI or API. Creation and snapshot operations may take 20-30 minutes.